# Several installations of Ubuntu 16.04 configured to obtain IP address automatically are occasionally losing IP address and disconnecting from network

Tags: networking, 16.04, xubuntu, network-manager, dhcp

I am seeing an issue on multiple servers and VM's with various Ubuntu 16.04 distributions installed (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Xubuntu 16.04, Mythbuntu 16.04) and are configured to obtain IP address automatically with DHCP where  the IP address obtained by DHCP is removed from the system.    Frequency of occurrences is varied - can be multiple days in a row, and could be 30+ days between occurrences.

I have determined that for some reason when this issue occurs, it seems dhclient renews the lease before it expires but for some reason this does not seem to be seen by NetworkManager as there are not NetworkManager log entries in syslog or kern.log, but there are such entries for successful renewals indicating the renewal was received and the interface was updated with the new expiry.

My leases are 24 hours, and when this occurs, after exactly 24 hours since the last dhclient renewal that was seen by NetworkManager, the IP is removed from the interface.

I did not see any occurrences of this on any server or VM until after an update that installed network-manager 1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 in November.

Syslog entries for successful renewals:

```
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> dhclient[1036]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.11 on ens160 to 192.168.2.1 port 67 (xid=0x35fe6348)
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> dhclient[1036]: DHCPACK of 192.168.2.11 from 192.168.2.1
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> NetworkManager[847]: <info>  [1485299792.2921]   address 192.168.2.11
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> NetworkManager[847]: <info>  [1485299792.2926]   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> NetworkManager[847]: <info>  [1485299792.2926]   gateway 192.168.2.1
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> NetworkManager[847]: <info>  [1485299792.2926]   server identifier 192.168.2.1
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> NetworkManager[847]: <info>  [1485299792.2926]   lease time 86400
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> NetworkManager[847]: <info>  [1485299792.2926]   nameserver '192.168.2.1'
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> NetworkManager[847]: <info>  [1485299792.2926] dhcp4 (ens160): state changed bound -> bound
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> dhclient[1036]: bound to 192.168.2.11 -- renewal in 40856 seconds.
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> dbus[810]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> dbus[810]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [ens160]: new request (1 scripts)
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [ens160]: start running ordered scripts...
```

Kernel.log entries for successful renewals:

```
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> NetworkManager[847]: <info>  [1485299792.2921]   address 192.168.2.11
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> NetworkManager[847]: <info>  [1485299792.2926]   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> NetworkManager[847]: <info>  [1485299792.2926]   gateway 192.168.2.1
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> NetworkManager[847]: <info>  [1485299792.2926]   server identifier 192.168.2.1
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> NetworkManager[847]: <info>  [1485299792.2926]   lease time 86400
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> NetworkManager[847]: <info>  [1485299792.2926]   nameserver '192.168.2.1'
Jan 24 15:16:32 <hostname> NetworkManager[847]: <info>  [1485299792.2926] dhcp4 (ens160): state changed bound -> bound
```

Syslog entries for renewals not seen by Network Manager.   Note the complete absence of NetworkManager entries.

```
Jan 25 23:04:54 <hostname> dhclient[1036]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.11 on ens160 to 192.168.2.1 port 67 (xid=0x35fe6348)
Jan 25 23:04:54 <hostname> dhclient[1036]: DHCPACK of 192.168.2.11 from 192.168.2.1
Jan 25 23:04:54 <hostname> dhclient[1036]: bound to 192.168.2.11 -- renewal in 42517 seconds.
```

Kernel.log entries for renewals not seen by network manager - there are absolutely none leading me to conclude that the renewal performed by dhclient did not update the lease information for the interface which is why the IP was removed from the interface when the old lease entry expired.

As mentioned above, frequency is not predictable - this can go 30+ days between occurrences and can also happen within a couple days or less of previous occurence.  When IP is lost, logs also show more than one renewal not properly processed and interface updated since last successful renewal.   There are also cases where a single renewal fails to be processed but a subsequent renewal occurs and is successful before the lease from the last successfully processed renewal expires.

I am fairly confident I could work around this by configuring a static IP for the servers, but I would prefer to resolve this issue and leave it to my DHCP server to hand out the statically mapped IP.